# How to apply Application.ShortcutMenus so the Macro still appears when right-clicking a table?

Tags: excel, vba

There seems to be very little online around this, so some input here would be very useful.

I have used the below code to add an option to a right-click menu:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim MyMenu As Object

Set MyMenu = Application.ShortcutMenus(xlWorksheetCell) _
    .MenuItems.AddMenu("Opportunities", 1)

With MyMenu.MenuItems
    .Add "Open", "openOpportunity", , 1, , ""
    .Add "Edit", "editOpportunity", , 2, , ""
End With

Set MyMenu = Nothing

End Sub
```

This adds an option to the right-click menu when I right-click in a cell, but when I right-click a cell in an Excel table, it doesn't appear.

Any ideas where I go next?

Comment: You will find that right click menus are context sensitive so you need to add a menu item for each context in which you want your menu item to appear.

Comment: @dhumphreys: You must also add your controls on 'List Range Popup' menu. I cannot extract the shortcut menu index in order to use your code. Please see my answer, like an alternative of doing exactly what you need.

Comment: `xlWorksheetCell = 3`, but I cannot find the necessary value for 'List Range Popup' menu, in order to keep your code type. I took it like a challenge and I am still digging, but no result, yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also must add your options to 'List Range Popup'. I am not familiar with the way you do that and I don't know how to obtain the necessary Command bar index, so I will show you my way to do exactly what you need, in the next code:

```
Sub AddButContextMenu()
  Dim CMenu_Cell As CommandBar, MySubMCell As CommandBarControl
  Dim CMenu_Table As CommandBar, MySubMTable As CommandBarControl
    'Delete the controls first, in order to avoid duplicates
    Call DeleteFromCellMenu
    'Set ContextMenu to the Cell menu and List Range Popup
    Set CMenu_Cell = Application.CommandBars(35)  'Cell menu
    Set CMenu_Table = Application.CommandBars(71) 'List Range Popup
     Set MySubMCell = CMenu_Cell.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, Before:=3)
     Set MySubMTable = CMenu_Table.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, Before:=3)

    With MySubMCell
        .Caption = "Opportunities"
        .Tag = "My_Tag"
        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "openOpportunity"
            .Caption = "Open"
        End With
        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "editOpportunity"
            .Caption = "Edit"
        End With
    End With
    With MySubMTable
        .Caption = "Opportunities"
        .Tag = "My_Tag"
        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "openOpportunity"
            .Caption = "Open"
        End With
        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "editOpportunity"
            .Caption = "Edit"
        End With
    End With

    CMenu_Cell.Controls(4).BeginGroup = True 'add separator
    CMenu_Table.Controls(4).BeginGroup = True 'add separator
End Sub
Sub DeleteFromCellMenu()
    Dim ContextMCell As CommandBar, ContextMTable As CommandBar
    Dim ctrl As CommandBarControl

    Set ContextMCell = Application.CommandBars(35)  'Cell
    Set ContextMTable = Application.CommandBars(71) 'List Range Popup

    For Each ctrl In ContextMCell.Controls
        If ctrl.Tag = "My_Tag" Then
            ctrl.Delete
        End If
    Next ctrl
    For Each ctrl In ContextMTable.Controls
        If ctrl.Tag = "My_Tag" Then
            ctrl.Delete
        End If
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

If interested, I can show you a method to identify all shortcut menus...