# Create Excel VBA custom right click menu for specified range

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to create a custom right click menu item in an Excel sheet, which would trigger a macro, with the constraint that the menu item would only be visible in a pre-defined range (e.g. A1:B2)?

Below code would create the custom menu item, but it's not yet constrained to range A1:B2. How could this code be adjusted so that the custom menu only appears in the predefined range?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()   
    
    Dim MyMenu As Object        
    
    Set MyMenu = Application.ShortcutMenus(xlWorksheetCell) _
                    .MenuItems.AddMenu("This is my Custom Menu", 1)

    With MyMenu.MenuItems    
        .Add "MyMacro1", "MyMacro1", , 1, , ""    
        .Add "MyMacro2", "MyMacro2", , 2, , ""    
    End With  
    Set MyMenu = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub mymacro1()
    MsgBox "Macro1 from a right click menu"
End Sub
    
Public Sub mymacro2()
    MsgBox "Macro2 from a right click menu"
End Sub
```

Would it at the same time be possible to remove the standard items in the right click menu for that same range?

If so, could you please help me with the code?

Thank you.

Kind regards
Jan

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60276171/how-to-apply-application-shortcutmenus-so-the-macro-still-appears-when-right-cli

Comment: Did you look into the suggestion you got when you first posted this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the cell menu popUp is triggered by right click **on a cell**. Any cell, except the case when it is part of a table. Theoretically, you may transform the range you need the new added command to be part of context menu **in a table**. But in such a case the menu you must customize should be `List Range Popup`. There are two inconveniences, respectively: From the range of two rows, one for them must be the header (which is not so easy to change if needed) and the desired commands will be part of the context menu **for all tables** ('listObjects`)...

So, I will try showing a workaround able to place the commands only if the right click is made on the respective cells, and be deleted for the other ones.

1. Please, copy the following event code in `ThisWorkbook` code module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim cB1 As CommandBarButton, cB2 As CommandBarButton
    
    DelCommands 'delete the custom commands for all cells...
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("A1:B2")) Is Nothing Then 'if right click is applied to the necessary range:
        'add the two necessary commands:
        Set cB1 = Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)
          cB1.Caption = "MyMacro1": cB1.OnAction = "MyMacroA"
            
        Set cB2 = Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)
          cB2.Caption = "MyMacro2": cB2.OnAction = "MyMacroB"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DelCommands()
    On Error Resume Next
      Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls("MyMacro1").Delete
      Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls("MyMacro2").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

2. And the called Subs in **a standard module**:

```
Sub MyMacroA()
   MsgBox ActiveCell.address, vbInformation, "MyMacroA"
End Sub

Sub MyMacroB()
   MsgBox ActiveCell.address(0, 0), vbInformation, "MyMacroB"
End Sub
```

This adapted context menu will appear (in the respective range) **in all worksheets**. If you want to limit it only to specific ones, you should play with `sh.name`, too...

Comment: Thank you so much, FaneDuru! This code works beautifully!!

Comment: @Jan V Glad I could help! But I would like to tell you that we here, when somebody answer our question in a convenient way, tick the code left side check box in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the suggested solution works.